# Inertia indices in GAP

Tags: linear-algebra, gap

Not sure that this is the right place, but I could not find a GAP specific forum.

Does anyone know if there is a built-in function in GAP to find the inertia indices of a symmetric matrix, say, over Integers or Rationals? Of course I have something written "on the knee" but apparently it's too slow: for a $(4600\times4600)$-integer matrix it works slower than SmithNormalForm, which does not seem normal.

Comment: GAP specific forum: go to https://github.com/gap-system/gap/discussions or use the GAP Forum mailing list https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html or ask on the GAP slack: https://gap-system.org/slack

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!